# maximum number of arguments postgresql function can take

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.2

I have a view consists of two table. Let's say table TableA and table TableB.

Now table A has got around 20 columns and table B has go 4 columns.

```
TableA (
  id datatype,
  uid datatype,
  .  
  .   
  .
  18 more);

TableB (
  id datatype,
  uid datatype,
  a_id datatype,
  amount datatype,
  CONSTRAINT tablea_tableb_fkey FOREIGN KEY (a_id)
      REFERENCES tablea (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE RESTRICT ON DELETE RESTRICT,
);
```

So there is one to many relationship between TableA and TableB. Now I have written the view as follows...

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW AB AS 
 SELECT a.id, a.uid, ..., array_agg(b.amount) AS amounts
   FROM TableA a
   JOIN TableB b ON a.id = b.a_id
  GROUP BY i.id;
```

Now I want to write insert rule for this view which I am doing by writing a helper function. The function takes around 18 parameters (except `id`, `uid` has default value) for inserting into TableA and 1 parameter which is an Array for TableB.

So the total parameters for function is 19. I want to know what is the maximum number of arguments that I can pass to function in `postgresql`? Is it wise to send this many number of arguments? Is there any better way to write the function for this many number of arguments?

Comment: to check the max function args I used following query in postgresql 9.2. 
select * from pg_settings where name='max_function_args';

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FUNC_MAX_ARGS is one compilation parameter (you can change it and recompile), and on my 9.2 source code is 100.

If you have more parameters, then using a arrays is a good idea.